# java.util.Scanner does not return to Prompt

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class newClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

This program does not return to prompt (I have been running it through the Terminal). Why is that? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***This program does not return to prompt (I have been running it through the Terminal). Why is that?***

Because `s.hasNext()` will block until further input is available and will only return false if it encounters end of stream.

From the docs:

> *Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan.***

On a unix system you can end the stream by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which correctly returns control to the prompt, (or terminate the whole program by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

> ***How can I correct it?***

You can either

- reserve some input string used for terminating the program, as suggested by JJ, or
- you could rely on the user closing the input stream with Ctrl+D, or you could
- enclose the loop in a try/catch and let another thread interrupt the main thread which then exits gracefully.
- do `System.in.close()` programatically from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. one more thing. let's say if I reserve the word "quit" for System.exit(0), then if i enter "i can't quit chocolate". that too will end at quit and also go to prompt. so I am thinking i should add a line at the start of the program that asks the user to press Ctrl + C to end. C

Comment: Just a request. Can you post the try/catch solution somewhere?. Thanks

Comment: also what could be used for End of stream? is there any delimiter?

Comment: just do, `try { your while loop } catch(InterruptedException ie) { exit gracefully }`, and from another thread, do `if (exitCondition) mainThread.interrupt()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a reply to a comment above. Here, the application will quit when receiving "quit".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class newClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String temp = s.next();
            if(temp.trim().equals("quit"))
                System.exit(0);
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner will block waiting for input from System.in (standard input). You have to press Ctrl+C to exit the program, close the Input stream by pressing Ctrl+D or give the loop an exit condition (like typing "quit"), here is how you could do that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class newClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String nextVal = s.next();
            if (nextVal.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) { break; }
            System.out.println(nextVal);
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: waiting for reply "When I type quit, it just echoes the word "quit" and still doesn't exit"....

Comment: quit is not equal to EOF. You must have an if comparing the input to the "quit" string for this to work.

Comment: I guess he meant you've to reserve a word like 'quit' and check for that in the `while` loop condition.

Comment: Or close the input stream by hitting Ctrl+D.