# Infinite loop on one hand, NoSuchElementException on the other

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop, nosuchelementexception

I recently asked if there is any possible way whatsoever to get an exception from assigning a value to a String variable with the `Scanner` (The thread is [***here:***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331645/type-safety-of-input-nextline))

And one of the guys told me that CTRL+D would be a case where a `NoSuchElementException` could be thrown. This to me is kind of a special case because `input.nextLine()` returns a String, and a String can be basically anything a user could type on the keyboard, so one would assume that `input.nextLine()` would not be a concern to throw an exception.

So I decided to add some try catch blocks into a program I'm writing on the off chance that CTRL+D is pressed when the program is asking for a number.

The problem I've run into is that when I catch the CTRL+D exception, the `Scanner` needs to be flushed, but if I flush the `Scanner`, it will cause a `NoSuchElementException` to occur because no new line exists. I'm using this all in a while true loop, so I'm kind of stuck between a rock and a hard place.

I will post one version of the code, with the `input.nextLine()` commented out. If you run it as is, you will get the infinite loop that happens when the `Scanner` needs to be flushed. If you uncomment the `input.nextLine()`, that very line of code will itself cause a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;



private int getMainOptions(){

    System.out.printf("\n********** Main Options **********");
    System.out.printf("\n*%32s*", "");
    System.out.printf("\n*  %-30s*", "[1] Create Customer");
    System.out.printf("\n*  %-30s*", "[2] Create Reservation");
    System.out.printf("\n*  %-30s*", "[3] Display Customer");
    System.out.printf("\n*  %-30s*", "[4] Display Reservation");
    System.out.printf("\n*%32s*", "");
    System.out.printf("\n**********************************");

    while(true){
        try{

            System.out.print("\nChoose Option: ");

            if(input.hasNextInt()){
                return input.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.print("\nInvalid option");
            input.nextLine();
            continue;
        }

        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.print("\nAn exception occurred.");
            //input.nextLine();
        } 
    } 


}
```

Apart from creating the Scanner inside the while loop and destoying it in the catch to be recreated in the next iteration, what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Aren't we supposed to rely on Ctrl+d as a UNIX command to  return control to the prompt? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7107482/2568511). Are you sure it's bad?

Comment: Have you tried using `input.hasNextLine()` before calling `nextLine()`? In fact you already use that for int... use it for line too.

Comment: Just tested it now...if I check for hasNextLine() first, it goes into the same infinite loop that happens when the code is run with the input.nextLine() commented out exactly as written above

Answer (score 0):

The code goes into an infinite loop when the `input.nextLine()` is commented out or when `input.hasNextLine()` is there to check because it is in a `while(true)` loop with nothing to stop it since `input.nextInt()` is not called. `if(input.hasNextInt())` will not wait for an int, but simply skip the code inside the if statement if an int is not present as input.
Instead try this:

```
while(true){
    try{
        System.out.print("\nChoose Option: ");
        String in=input.nextLine();
        try{
            int i=Integer.parseInt(in);
            return i;
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            System.out.print("\nInvalid option");
        }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.print("\nAn exception occurred.");
        //input.nextLine();
    } 
} 
}
```

I hope this helps and that I am understanding the question correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you fully grasp what happens when the user presses Ctrl-D.  When that happens the standard input stream is closed.  There is no way to reopen a closed stream.  Even if you create a new `Scanner` and pass it in `System.in` it will still throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

As a Linux user if I press Ctrl-D in an interactive program, I expect the program to terminate.  That is really all you can do at that point.